# IPhone app notifications have a 30 second to 1 min delay

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

We have an iPhone app which uses firebase to handle in app notifications (chat notifications, push notifications) which are having a 30 seconds to 1 min delay before they arrive. The Android app does not have this issue. What do we need to correct? Thanks in advance.

The notifications should arrive promptly in real time as they are pushed or a chat message is received. Chat messages are received as floating notifications when the app is minimised.

Answer (score 1):

We have same issue and finally resolved it. Hope it can help you as well.

In our case, the problem was UNNotificationServiceExtension. We are using UNNotificationServiceExtension to handle push images.

The issue we faced was the lack of exception handling when parsing fcm_options.

On our server, if a push notification does not include an image, 'fcm_options' is sent as null. And in cases where it , we needed to return the default push. If a push isn't returned within a specific timeframe, approximately 30 seconds, the serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire() method is triggered to return the default push.

```
let contentHandler: ((UNNotificationContent) -> Void)?
let content: UNMutableNotificationContent?

override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
  self.contentHandler = contentHandler
  content = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)
  if let content, let fcmOptionsUserInfo = content.userInfo["fcm_options"] as? [String: Any] {
    ...
  } else {
    // if payload does not have fcm_options, should return default push
    contentHandler(content)
  }
}

override func serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire() {
  if let contentHandler, let content {
    contentHandler(content)     // <-- If the push is not returned within a certain time frame in didReceive(), the default push is automatically returned.
  }
}
```